# Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to install Green UML, it said:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>       Software being installed: Green 3.5.0 (Green.feature.group 3.5.0)
>       Missing requirement: Green 3.5.0 (Green.feature.group 3.5.0) requires   'org.eclipse.core.boot 0.0.0' but it could not be found,

How can I install `org.eclipse.core.boot 0.0.0`? I have tried many other UML tools and always got the same error. I am using **Eclipse Juno**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your UML plugin needs [Eclipse Core Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Core_Tools)

Get it from here: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/downloads.php

Both the UML Tools, `Green UML` and `euml2`, that you mentioned, don't show support for Eclipse Juno as of now. May be thats why they're not working. They show versions compatibility up until Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)

Comment: the functionalities of Green is limited, then i tried to install eUML2,it said  it required org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore [2.6.0,2.7.0), where can i locate this?maybe you call teach me how to solve this kind of problem,i already saw lots of problems like this,it is very annoying

Comment: well the uml tools you're trying to install are plugin's, right ? when you get these kind of things missing error messages, in this case `org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore` , search it using google. you'll find the name of that missing library. then install that missing plugin from eclipse market place. look here, http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/, they don't support eclipse juno versions as of now. may be that is why its not working with your eclipse.

Comment: thanks, i am c# programmer, i am just turning into java,i searched it using google, but it is very difficult to find which package the lost file belongs,what is wrong with Judo? what's the difference between judo,halos,or something else? and which version i should choose in the official site, at least , it can install UML tools without these annoying problems.Thanks your time.

Comment: well you could always start by using helios ie 3.6, lots of plugins are supported for that version. They've just named 3.6 helios, 3.7 indigo and 4.2 juno. don't know why that is. Even if you use 3.6, you can change into a newer version on a later day, without much hassle. try using helios and check if these plugins are working. Read this if confused by eclipse's plugin installation http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to run Green UML on Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), then add

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

to sites at Help -> Install new software.

Comment: ^ This. Magic.

Tried it as a fix in Luna though, and it pretends to look like it works but in fact, does not.